# How can I get the score of k-means without training?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am running `MiniBatchKMeans` in a script and outputting the cluster centers I get. Now in another script I want to calculate the score of the test set with those cluster centers. I've tried to do this:

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, init=cluster_centers)
print mbk.score(X)
```

but I am getting this exception

```
AttributeError: Model has not been trained yet.
```

How can I get the score of k-means without training the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to restore the clusterer's `cluster_centers_` attribute. The standard way to do this is to [pickle your model](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#model-persistence), saving it to disk (rather than merely printing the centroids), and then load it up to score the test data.

In the training script:

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k, ...)
mbk.fit(X)
import pickle
pickle.dump(mbk, open('/path/to/mbk.pickle', 'wb'))
```

In the testing script:

```
import pickle
mbk = pickle.load(open('/path/to/mbk.pickle', 'rb'))
print mbk.score(X)
```

Alternatively, it may suffice to use your current code, and in the testing script do:

```
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k)
mbk.cluster_centers_ = cluster_centers
mbk.score(X)
```

but this may not be guaranteed to always work.